# kafka customet partioner error

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

i wrote custom partitioner program,both class in same project but not sure why i am getting below error.Please help me on this.Below program is a  kafka producer program.When i run the program i am getting error as SensorPartitioner class not found.

error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value SensorPartitioner for configuration partitioner.class: Class SensorPartitioner could not be found.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:671)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:418)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:56)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:63)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.java:338)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:188)
    at kafka.test.main(test.java:19)



package kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Properties;
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    System.out.println("new");
     String topicName = "partitionTopic";
     String sCurrentLine;
     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,localhost:9093");
     props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
     props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
     props.put("partitioner.class", "SensorPartitioner");
     props.put("speed.sensor.name", "core");
     Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer <String, String>(props);

          try{

     BufferedReader br = null;
     br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("datagen_10.txt"));
          //String arr1=" ";
          while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

              System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
              String[] arr11 = sCurrentLine.split(",");
              String key=arr11[0];
          ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName,key,sCurrentLine);
          RecordMetadata metadata = producer.send(record).get();
          System.out.println("Message is sent to Partition no " + metadata.partition() + " and offset " + metadata.offset());
           System.out.println("SynchronousProducer Completed with success.");
      }
          br.close();
      }catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           System.out.println("SynchronousProducer failed with an exception");
      }finally{
           producer.close();
      }
   }
}

 below program is custom partitioner program.


package kafka;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.record.*;

public class SensorPartitioner implements Partitioner {

     private String speedSensorName;

     public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
          speedSensorName = configs.get("speed.sensor.name").toString();

     }

     public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {

           List<PartitionInfo> partitions = cluster.partitionsForTopic(topic);
           int numPartitions = partitions.size();
           int sp = (int)Math.abs(numPartitions*0.3);
           int p=0;

            if ( (keyBytes == null) || (!(key instanceof String)) )
                 throw new InvalidRecordException("All messages must have sensor name as key");

            if ( ((String)key).equals(speedSensorName) )
                 p = Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(valueBytes)) % sp;
            else
                 p = Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(keyBytes)) % (numPartitions-sp) + sp ;

                 System.out.println("Key = " + (String)key + " Partition = " + p );
                 return p;
  }
      public void close() {}

}
```

Comment: Try `props.put("partitioner.class", "kafka.SensorPartitioner");`

Answer (score 0):

I also met the same problem, but I found the SensorPartitioner instead of a Kafka class, actually is another class in the tutorial. You create the SensorPartitioner class, then the problem would be solved.

The class:
https://github.com/LearningJournal/ApacheKafkaTutorials/blob/master/ProducerExamples/SensorPartitioner.java

Answer (score 0):

vivman I had the same problem with IDEA devTools.And I fixed it by set fullPath to `partitioner.class` like this `props.put("partitioner.class", "xx.xxx.x.SensorPartitioner");` in you program you can try to modify like this `props.put("partitioner.class", "kafka.SensorPartitioner");`

hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Use absolute path to SensorPartitioner class as below:

```
props.put("partitioner.class", "com.subpackage.subsubpackage.SensorPartitioner");
```